# Is there a way to extract metadata about a SPARK-ML Model/CrossValidator that gives input and output?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

i'm building a REST service for scoring against ML pipelines created in Spark ML. For this I'd need to know the input data format (attribute names and types) and output data format for predictions.
Lets say i have the following

```
    formula = RFormula(
    formula="approve ~ age + balance + jobIndx + maritalIndx + housingIndx + loanIndx + educationIndx + poutcomeIndx",
    featuresCol="features",
    labelCol="label")
    lr = LogisticRegression()
    trainingPipeline = Pipeline(stages=[jobIndx,
                                maritalIndx,
                                educationIndx,
                                housingIndx,
                                loanIndx,
                                poutcomeIndx,
                                formula,
                                lr])
```

Is there a way to extract information about the Pipeline **trainingPipeline** on what the expected input (features: age, balance, jobIndx etc.) and output (label: approve) is (without the fact of knowing the RFormula)? 
Likewise, if i build a complete ML pipeline and use a CrossValidator for model tuning like

```
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
    .addGrid(lr.maxIter, [10,1000]) \
    .addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.1, 0.6]) \
    .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0.1, 0.9])\
    .build()

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=trainingPipeline,
                          estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                          evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
                          numFolds=3)
cvModel = crossval.fit(dfTraining)
prediction = cvModel.transform(dfTest)
```

From the CrossValidator **crossval** in above example, is there a way to extract the structure of what has to go into the CrossValidator transform method (dfTest in above example). 
I'd like to create a REST contract for scoring against a Pipeline or CrossValidator by just introspecting a Model, Pipeline or CrossValidator object and I'm wondering if this can be done. By looking at what [MLeap](http://mleap-docs.combust.ml/) does it seems possible but wondering if you have some PySpark or Java code that would show how to do this.

Comment: What metadata are you looking for? Pipeline like this doesn't strictly determine input data. In general case the best you can do is determine column names, not types.

Comment: Column names would be ok for now, most of the models require numeric input anyway, at least the ones have looked at so far.

Comment: In that case you can usually easily retrieve data from individual `Transformers`  / `Estimators` by getting `inputCol(s)` / `outputCol(s)`. `RFormula` is trickier, but not impossible. Then you create a graph of dependencies, to find out which columns must be present in the input.